# Converting xlsx to xlsb

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, spreadsheet

I recently discovered the benefits to converting Excel documents to XLSB (binary), mostly the cutting almost in half of file sizes.

I would like to apply this to some of my older files, but don't want to sit around resaving these documents.

That macro should be able to search through the whole C:\ drive find only the XLSX files open it and save it in .xlsb file format in the same folder with the same name by also retaining the original .xlsx file.

Regards

Comment: Searching "Recursive VBA" here or on the wider net should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Savesheet()
'
' Save Macro
' Save to Server
'
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFileNm As String
strPath = "H:/"
' get file name from worksheet Sheet1 cell C2
strFileNm = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value & " OnShift RFI"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & strFileNm & ".xlsb", _
               FileFormat:=xlExcel52

End Sub
```

also, update the above macro according to this:

```
I believe the correct parameters look like this,

.SaveAs Filename:=strFileNm, FileFormat:=50   'xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or without macro's, xlsb)
```

[refer to this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/using-a-macro-to-save-as-xlsb/1fd77c30-22b5-4717-8df3-2c94c61fe138?db=5)

I googled and found the above link where it was given. No guarantee or troubleshooting from my side.